# Is there any intersection of EE and abstract mathematics?

Tags: soft-question

I'm a sophomore in Electrical Engineering and have a keen interest in abstract mathematics. As you know the mathematics taught in the first two years of engineering is nothing but more applied mathematics comprising of Fourier/Laplace/Z transforms, some linear algebra, numerical methods and probability.

I, on the other hand, am interested in pure mathematics. I try to study on my own whenever I get time from my engineering course. Its not that I dislike my EE course but I am more inclined towards pure mathematics.

Is there any intersection of the two, in which I can pursue my MS/further studies. Something which gives me a flavor of both? Sorry for the long post and if my question appears too vague. I'm hoping to get some guiding light from the esteemed members of this forum.

Comment: In 2010 IPAM (at UCLA) had a [conference](https://www.ipam.ucla.edu/programs/opws1/) about "convex optimization and algebraic geometry".

Comment: You could also read about [Claude Shannon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Shannon), whose career was defined by the intersection of EE and math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some may define "pure" mathematics as those branches that do not have applications. Assuming you meant "mathematics not generally taught to EE majors", then here are some places to start:

- Topology is being used for [applications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyG-A8D1KDE) in signal processing and path finding for robotics.
- Lie Algebras are being used to describe and control the movements of [robotic joints](http://www.prometheus-us.com/asi/algebra2003/papers/selig.pdf).
- Graph theory is used in object recognition and other methods of computer vision.

Comment: Algebraic topology is also used for sensor networks. See, for instance, [Homological Sensor Networks](http://www.ams.org/notices/200701/fea-ghrist.pdf) by de Silva and Ghrist.

Comment: See also Michael Robinson's recent book: [Topological Signal Processing](http://www.springer.com/engineering/signals/book/978-3-642-36103-6).